# autosum entered using vba shows zero as result

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to enter an autosum in the last row of my column and although the calculation looks correct in excel it is showing zero as the result.

Please see attached image showing the result, when i enter the exact same formula into excel directly the autosum works fine.

Image showing excel sheet result

[image]

```
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "J").Value = "=Sum(J2:J" & lastrow & ")"
```

Comment: Because you will have a circular reference. Surprised that Excel didn't notify you. The formula in `lastrow` is referencing itself, i.e. summing up to and including `lastrow`.

Comment: One way... `"=Sum(J2:J" & lastrow & ")"` should be `"=Sum(J2:J" & lastrow - 1 & ")"`

Comment: Second way. Change `ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "J").Value` to `ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow +1, "J").Value`

Comment: thank you, it's now working! excel did not warn me about the circular reference.

Comment: Or use R1C1 referencing: `ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "J").FormulaR1c1 = "=Sum(R2C:R[-1]C)"`